# Enable a textbox when a checkbox is selected

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a dialog which contains a checkbox and a textbox. The textbox should only be enabled when the checkbox is checked.

Currently I tried doing this with the following binding.

```
CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox("Enable textbox");
TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
tbox.disableProperty().bind(cbox.selectedProperty());
```

This however has the exact opposite effect that I want (The textbox becomes disabled when I select the checkbox). And I can't find an "enableProperty" on textbox.

I have found that the textbox has a "editableProperty()", and binding that to the selectedProperty has parts of the desired effect that I want. However, I feel disabling would still be a better option, as it's visually more intuitive.

It's probably an easy fix, but how exactly do I have to bind the properties to enable the textbox when the checkbox is selected?

Comment: Use [`BooleanExpression#not()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanExpression.html#not()) or [`Bindings#not(ObservableBooleanValue)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#not(javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue)) on the `selected` property. For example: `...bind(cbox.selectedProperty().not());`.

Comment: @Slaw Yep, that did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tbox.disableProperty().bind(cbox.selectedProperty());
```

That means when the cbox is selected the tbox will disable. You can use the not property:

```
tbox.disableProperty().bind(cbox.selectedProperty().not());
```